# How to check times in milliseconds in android

Tags: java, android, milliseconds, chronometer

I've got a milliseconds chronometer that works fine.
Button code:

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);
                txtCheck.setText("");
            }
        });
```

Runnable:

```
 Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    timeMilliSeconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime;
    updateTime = timeSwapBuff+timeMilliSeconds;
    secs = (int)(updateTime/1000);
    mins = (int)(secs/60);
    secs %=60;
    milliseconds = (int)(updateTime%1000);
    txtChrono.setText(""+mins+":"+String.format("%2d",secs)+":"
                                +String.format("%3d",milliseconds));
    customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
      check(secs, milliseconds)  
    }
};
```

Function to check if time matches:

```
 public void check(Integer secs, long milli){
    if (secs.equals(45) && milli.equals(367)){
        txtCheck.setText("done");
    }
}
```

I need to check the time in order to start an event. The times I have to check are in seconds.milliseconds (i.e. 45.367), but this function (check) does not work.
Any idea?

The 'check' function works... but only 1 out of five times: maybe the refreshing time is too low?
Also, the code is in a fragment: does it have any influence on timer?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What is the expected result und what are you getting instead? Why are you using .postDelayed method with delay of 0? Also you should maybe format your code a bit better for readability.

Comment: A primitive data type don't have a equals-method. You should use "==" or wrap it with `Long.parseLong();` And a Runnable isn't a thread, it's a task which can executed by a Thread.

Comment: @nulldroid. I've changed the code to make it more clear(?). I do not know why am I using .postDelayed with 0 delay (I've copied the code from a tutorial) and the chronometer works.

Comment: @LinuxServer. Same results with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your calculations take longer than 1 millisecond. You should not check that often. It's expensive and not safe.
Why not use a [CountdownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)? It does the job and it's based on milliseconds.

```
 private long[] checkTimes = new long[]{ 45367L,90446L,25384L}; 
 for (int i = 0; i < checkTimes.length; i++) {
    new CountDownTimer(checkTimes[i], 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             txtCheck.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             txtCheck.setText("done");
         }
      }.start();
 }
```

Comment: It works. Would you please help me to do it n times? I mean that I need to add a function to repeat it several times (with different lengths).

Comment: added a simple for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this to get the in Millisecond :

```
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: What's the difference between System.currentTimeMillis and System.upTimeMillis? Should I calculate 45 seconds and 367 milliseconds or directly 45367 milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Android `Instant` class as described here?
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/time/Instant

It's been a huge help for me when doing the same type of work you are.

Comment: Do you know an example of that class?